# Could anyone pls convert this unixtime stamp in php?

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am struggling with this unixtimestamp and just cant find a correct format

Here is the stamp:

```
1295058844
```

And here is the result i want to achive:

```
01/14/2011 at 21:34 EST
```

And here is my almost correct but no luck code:

```
$start_unixtime = '1295058844';
date('m/d/Y \a\t H:i', intval($start_unixtime));
```

Basically i want EST time format, hope someone could help and sorry for such stupid question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the date_default_timezone_set function before you call date.

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
```

List of possible choices.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Eastern time != Atlantic time.

Comment: @amber Thats why I gave a list of real choices in the link.  I didn't feel like looking it up.

Comment: When I commented, you didn't have a link. :)

Comment: I believe all agree that it will be fair to choose that answer as it was the first and made perfect sense :) Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

No need for `intval`.

```
date_default_timezone_set("TIMEZONENAME");
$start_unixtime = '1295058844';
echo date('m/d/Y \a\t H:i', $start_unixtime);
```

Comment: Not a matter of `intval()` but a matter of timezone offset.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe to get your "at" into there: date('m/d/Y',$x).' at '.date('H:i',$x)

After that I never could remember the codes, I tend to look them up every time.